# Manim CE unexpected behavior with the Succession Class when animating several times the same object

Tags: manim

I am using manim Community Edition v0.15.1 to do math animations. I want to use the Succession class to programatically create a series of animations that must happen one after the other (one animation starts when the previous has finished). Here is the code that I have:

```
from manim import *

class SuccessionExample(Scene): 
    def construct(self): 
        dot1 = Dot(point=LEFT * 2 + UP * 2, radius=0.16, color=BLUE)    
        self.add(dot1)    
        self.play(Succession(
        dot1.animate.shift(UP),
        dot1.animate.shift(DOWN),
        dot1.animate.shift(LEFT),

    ))
```

I would expect my dot to move up, then down, then left. However, my point only moves left. I checked this issue that describes the same problem, but if I understood correctly the solution is to modify the source code, and the creator of the package seems to have modified it in his own personal version of Manim (not CE).

I don't know how to modify the source code, nor where to find the version fixed by the creator of the package.

My question is: how do I programmatically create a succession of animations for the same object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.animate` schema cannot be used several times in the same `.play()` or same `Succession()`.

But you can instead use the animation `ApplyMethod()` which allows to execute any method (in this case `.shift`) as part of a sequence of animations.

The syntax is a bit weird, because you have to pass first the object.method you want to call, and then the arguments, but it allows you to create a list of animations that can be passed to `Succession()` as it is your intention:

```py
class Test(Scene): 
    def construct(self): 
        dot1 = Dot(point=LEFT * 2 + UP * 2, radius=0.16, color=BLUE)    
        self.add(dot1)    
        self.play(Succession(
            ApplyMethod(dot1.shift, UP),
            ApplyMethod(dot1.shift, DOWN),
            ApplyMethod(dot1.shift, LEFT),
    ))
```

Result:

[image: Result]

In fact, you can even use list comprehensions to avoid code repetition:

```py
        self.play(Succession(
            *[ApplyMethod(dot1.shift, direction) 
              for direction in [UP, DOWN, LEFT]]
        ))
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to use these strategy with animations such as TransformFromCopy?

Comment: I don't understand this comment. `TransformFromCopy` is a "normal" animation, not one based on `.animate` property, so no special tricks are required. Why do you ask? Do you have a particular case in which it does not work? If so, better open a new question (and you can close this one too)

Comment: I don't know if it is worth another question, but when I try this:
class modelling(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        dot1 = Dot(point=LEFT * 2 + UP * 2, radius=0.16, color=BLUE)   
        dot2 = Dot(point=RIGHT * 2 + UP *2, radius=0.16, color = YELLOW) 
        self.add(dot1)    
        self.play(Succession(
        ApplyMethod(dot1.shift, UP),
        ApplyMethod(dot1.shift, DOWN),
        ApplyMethod(dot1.shift, LEFT),
        TransformFromCopy(dot1, dot2)
    ))

dot2 appears at the beginning of the animation, not with the animation "TransformFromCopy"

Comment: It is almost impossible to read the code in a comment, but I think that the problem you describe is very common when using `Succession` or `AnimationGroup`. All the objects "mentioned" in any of the steps of the Succession are created in advance, before the first animation is played, unless the animation is of the kind "introducer" (FadeIn for example). And even in those cases, it fails sometimes. In these cases it is better to run each animation in a separate `self.play()`

Answer (score 0):

Before trying to debug your problem I suggest that you update to the current version of ManimCE 0.17.3.

Ok, I had a look at your code as well, yes, in a single `self.play()` you cannot run several animations on the same object. This has to do with the way, animations are analyzed and executed in Manim.

Why do you want to put all of this in a single `self.play()`?

In order to keep your timing and the acceleration/deceleration of the normal animation I modified the individual `self.play()`-calls:

```py
class SuccessionExample(Scene): 
    def construct(self): 
        dot1 = Dot(point=LEFT * 2 + UP * 2, radius=0.16, color=BLUE)    
        self.add(dot1)    
        self.play(dot1.animate.shift(UP), run_time=1/3, rate_func=rate_functions.ease_in_cubic)
        self.play(dot1.animate.shift(DOWN), run_time=1/3, rate_func=rate_functions.linear)
        self.play(dot1.animate.shift(LEFT), run_time=1/3, rate_func=rate_functions.ease_out_cubic)
        self.wait()
```

Want to learn more about the "secrets" being Manim: join us on [Discord](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/faq/general.html?highlight=discord#where-can-i-find-more-resources-for-learning-manim).